# Auto clear function using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up an auto delete function in excel so that cells are cleared once a date has passed.  In my worksheet I can get the code to work on the first line, but need some advice to extend the range so it covers all dates entered in column B after B2.

The worksheet has 8 columns of data that need clearing once the date has passed.

The code I am currently using is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

If Date > Range("B2").Value Then
    Range("B2:H2").ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: only cells containing dates? Are the cells formatted as dates? And do you mean Clear contents as per your code?

Comment: All the rows in column B are dates, and are formatted as dates.  All other data in columns C - H is just additional info (e.g. name, email address, phone number).

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant clear not delete!

Comment: What is wrong with your code as is? Is it supposed to do a comparison for all of column B against Date? Not just B2?

Comment: I would like it to check all entries in column B after B1 (which is the column title).  I just can't figure out how to extend the range it is checking and then subsquently clearing

Answer (score 1):

Try this where it finds the last used cell in the column B then loops from B2 to this lastRow checking if date is > cell value. It uses `union` to gather the ranges that are in the past and stores them in a variable clearRange. At the end, if clearRange is not nothing i.e. there were some dates in the past found, it clears the contents in one go.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim loopRange As Range
Dim clearRange As Range

Set loopRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

Dim currCell As Range

For Each currCell In loopRange

    If Date > currCell.Value2 Then

        If Not clearRange Is Nothing Then

            Set clearRange = Union(clearRange, currCell.Resize(, 7))

        Else

           Set clearRange = currCell.Resize(, 7)

        End If

    End If

Next currCell

If Not clearRange Is Nothing Then clearRange.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: That is brilliant, and clears all expired dates in column B - thank you so much.

Comment: Pleased to hear it.

Comment: Is there a way that if column B date has expired and clears that it can also clear the associated data in rows c - h next to it.   I really appreciate your help

Comment: You are literally my hero! Thank you so so much for that